# pythonでwebサイトからのhtml取得をしましたが文字化けします。

Tags: python

次のコードでhtmlを取得しましたが、

```
import urllib2
fp = urllib2.urlopen('http://2689.web.fc2.com/1989/GS/GS1.html')
html = fp.read()
fp.close()
```

次のように文字化けしてしまいます。

出力結果（一部）

```
<div class='score'>
<p class='data-ce'><span>4??8???@1???@?????h?[???@56,000?l</span></p>
<div class='float-clear'></div>
<table border='1' cellspacing='2' class='board1'>
```

どのようにしたら、文字化けを直せるでしょうか？教えてください、お願いします。

Answer (score 5):

`chardet`ライブラリの`detect`を使用すれば文字コードが判別できますので、それをUnicodeに`decode`すれば取得元がどんな文字コードでも対応できます。

```
import urllib
import chardet

url = 'http://2689.web.fc2.com/1989/GS/GS1.html'
# データ取得
data = ''.join(urllib.urlopen(url).readlines())
# エンコーディング判別
guess = chardet.detect(data)
# Unicode化
unicode_data = data.decode(guess['encoding'])
```

あとはBeautifulSoupなりPyQueryなりでスクレイピング等をすれば良いです。

参考URL：http://ymotongpoo.hatenablog.com/entry/20110103/1294032545

Answer (score 2):

```
html = fp.read()
```

これを

```
html = fp.read().decode('shift_jis')
```

このように変更すれば直せると思います。